# Xen virtual host is probably FSCKing - how do I verify?

Tags: linux, xen, boot, ext3, fsck

I have a Xen virtual machine that has been running for over a year under a decent load. I restarted it this morning, and it's been several hours booting. I think it's FSCKing itself. `xm list` shows that's it's using a lot of cpu. I can't `xm console` into it. `xenconsole: Could not open tty '/dev/pts/0': No such file or directory`. The filesystem is EXT3.

Is there any way for me to:

- See a boot log / console for the VM, so I can verify what it is doing?
- Find out how much longer the FSCKing is going to take?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The console error you are getting is very likely due to xenconsoled not running for some reason. You stated some super uptime, which leads me to believe you are still using Xen 3.1.x, which I believe had a few bugs in that area.

Try re-starting xenconsoled (literally, just type xenconsoled if its not already running i.e. you don't see it in 'ps'), it will correct the PTY references in xenstore and xm console should work again.

Really, that's the only way you're going to see progress of the FSCK, barring actual introspection, if indeed that is the hangup.

Comment: Thank you! Thank you!

It almost seemed like it was waiting for xenconsoled to finish booting.

Life is good again.